# Using VisualVM on tomcat 8 running on EC2

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, visualvm

I am trying to use VisualVM in my system to monitor a Tomcat instance running over EC2. I tried steps provided in multiple blogs about how to configure it, but still when I try to run tomcat it gives me following error.

`./catalina.sh: 5: /home/gvr/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/bin/setenv.sh: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote: not found`

I added following statement in `server.xml`

```
<listener classname="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener"
rmiregistryportplatform="10001"
rmiserverportplatform="10002"
uselocalports="true" />
```

And my `setenv.sh` is as follows

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
$CATALINA_OPTS
```

Besides this I have added, `catalina-jmx-remote.jar` in tomcat's **lib** directory

[image]

Could anyone please provide me some hint, what is possibly going wrong. I tried everything I have found related to configuring VisualVM

I am running Tomcat 8.0.18, java 8 over ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there are two issues

- formatting in setenv.sh, you need \ to split across lines
- last line $CATALINA_OPTS which tries to execute the arguments, hence -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote not found...

Suggested fix

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
echo $CATALINA_OPTS
```

Answer (score 1):

I also tried using the JmxRemoteLifecycleListener and it didn't work for me.

Here it is how I did it:
1)I choose 1005 as jmx port and my setenve.sh is like:

CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10005 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"

2) redirect using ssh the jmx port and the rmi

3) Run visualvm using the following uri: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:10005/jmxrmi

If you need more information have a look to this post:
http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-connect-a-java-profiler-like-visualvm-or-jconsole-to-a-remote-tomcat-running-on-amazon-ec2/